# Resize React Bootstrap Table column sizes with fixed minWidth

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I have a Bootstrap table where the columns are toggled. Due to the number of columns, I need to use horizontal flow to make it all fit inside. However, the size of the header and the column itself gets too small to a point that it's unreadable. So I have to set up a minimum width for each column.
[image: Working as intended]

So, the columns should be in the whole table length at all times, and adapt the size to fill it all. However, when I am using the fixed minWidth and there are not many columns, the columns do not resize to fit the whole table. In the image below, the red square should not be appearing, but filled with the columns.
[image: Error image]

I have created a sandbox link with the table that does not resize correctly.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-almeida-9lgp2?file=/src/index.js

I have searched stack overflow to help me with the horizontal overflow, this is the CSS I have used to do so, by the way. I think this is the reason why the columns are not resizing as they should.

```
#table-employee-compensation {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  width: auto !important;
  table-layout: auto !important;
}
```

Thanks for your time to read this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved by adding `overflow: auto` to `.react-bootstrap-table`, removed  `width: auto !important;` and changed `display: block;` from the #table-employee-compensation class. Working as intended.